# How to extract error per data point using regression instead of just total sum of squares error

Tags: regression, error

I am running a regression and found the sum of squares error for my data points. I was wondering if there was a way to calculate the error per data point instead of just the total error. I want to look at the initial section of the fit (first ~30%) compared to the final ~70%.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, to get the residual for a unit of observation or data point $i$, you take the observed value of the dependent variable, $y_i$, minus the predicted value, which is the value on the dependent variable as predicted by the estimated regression model, $\hat{y}_i$. That is, you compute $y_i-\hat{y}_i$.